# Why is my program getting terminated when i enter user input?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, sparse-matrix

I was practicing some questions from hacker rank and got stuck in this question called sparse-arrays. (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sparse-arrays/problem) I am a beginner and i am not able to find out the error in my code. Please help. Thank you

I think I am not comparing the strings correctly. I tried using compare function but still it did not work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    string strings[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cin>>strings[i];
    }
    int m;
    cin>>m;
    string queries[m];
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
        cin>>queries[i];
    }

     //comparing
        for(int i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        int count=0;
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            if(queries[i]==strings[j])
                    count++;
        }
        cout<<count<<endl;
    }
}
```

The output should be the number of times the strings in (query) that have appeared in the (strings) but my program is getting terminated please help.

Comment: `string strings[n];` is high risk. So high that it's [not a part of Standard C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). Given a suitably high value for `n`, this will run your program out of Automatic storage and probably cause a Stack Overflow.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Please suggest me where should i practise from then, I'm really confused and trying hard to learn.

Comment: Suggestion: Back up your code. Then remove code bit by bit until you have a program that compiles, still crashes when the same input is given, and does nothing else. Usually reducing the noise of the good code around the bad code makes it easier to spot and fix the problem.

Comment: @YashAgrawal "_Please suggest me where should i practise from then_" From a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @user4581301 How should i take the input then sir please explain if it's possible.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for the suggestions. Please suggest a good book I'm really messed up.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Thankyou so much Sir.

Comment: [Link to excelent tutorial on debugging small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Another very handy tool is the debugger that almost certainly came with your development environment. If your environment doesn't have a debugger, get one that does. The debugger does a lot of things, but most important is it lets you to control the rate of the program's execution, allowing the slow human brain keep up and watch what the program does. When you observe the program running, keep an eye out for it doing the unexpected, like taking the wrong path or putting the wrong value in a variable. The unexpected is almost always a bug and when it isn't your expectations are wrong. Fix both.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you so much for the suggestions and for showing me the right way to learn things rather than saying the answer. I appreciate each bit of your help, thank you.

Comment: The following topic explains why VLAs are not part of c++ and gives you the c++ alternative: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Comment: The inner loop of your comparison code is infinite if `n` is positive (look carefully at the end condition - it is comparing two variables that are unchanged in the loop body).    That will cause `count` to overflow, which causes undefined behaviour.  Also, if for some reason, the loop terminates, `main()` also terminates, and - on many systems - the output window is destroyed before a mere human can see output.   Add some code immediately before the end of `main()` that flushes `cout` and waits for input before `main()` returns.

Comment: @Peter Thankyou sir, i made a really silly mistake i get it. I have to practice a lot more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int j=0; i<n; j++)
```

should be

```
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
```

Comment: I feel really embarrassed. This was such a silly mistake and me asking this on stack overflow further makes me feel more embarrassed. Thank you so much for the help Sir.

Comment: I had a question in my mind. Is it a better practice to use vector instead of VLAs in C++.

Comment: yes, definitely. I didn't address VLA as it was not your issue here, but still, stay away from them, and use vectors.

Comment: Sorry if it's a bad question. Can i ask why there is no risk of shortage of memory while using vectors but there is a high risk when using VLAs.

Comment: Because VLAs are allocated on the (limited) stack memory whereas vectors use heap storage, which is typically much more plentiful.

Comment: @YashAgrawal typical desktop today allows 1 MB to 10 MB for the Automatic storage (usually a stack). Dynamic storage (often implemented with a heap) is generally limited by the amount of addressable memory the computer has, typically in the gigabytes. A caveat with the term addressable: if you're using a 32 bit compiler the addressable storage is usually 2 or 4 GB (31 or 32 bits) no matter how much memory the computer has.